# A problem occurred evaluating project bluetooth_print

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, gradle, bluetooth-printing

I keep having a problem running my app.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go the module `:bluetooth_print` `build.gradle` and ...
replace all occurrences of `compile` with `implementation`.

Or update to a later version, which is compatible.